# The sums $\sum_{0\leq k}\binom{n}{2k}x^k$ and $\sum_{0\leq k}\binom{n}{2k+1}x^k$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

Let $n$ be a positive integer and suppose that 
$$
\sum_{0\leq k}\binom{n}{2k}x^k=A
$$
What can we say about the sum
$$
\sum_{0\leq k}\binom{n}{2k+1}x^k\ ? 
$$
Thanks!

**Edit:** Can we express the second sum using the value A of the first sum  ?

Comment: Hint: try to calculate the sum of the two sums

Comment: $k$ is in $\{0,\ldots,n\}$ in the sums ?

Comment: thanks Demien. can you please elaborate?

Comment: @boaz: Are the exponents on $x$ in the two summations correct? And since these summations are polynomials in $x$, are we to understand $A$ as a polynomial in $x$, or are they supposed to be evaluated at some specific $x$?

Comment: Hi Brian. The exponents are correct. x is suppose to be a specific value, so A is not a polynomial in x.

Comment: As the first sum is a polynomial of the order $\lfloor\frac n2\rfloor$ in $x$, the second sum can in general take on  $\lfloor\frac n2\rfloor$ different values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the equation 
$$
\sum_{0\leq k}\binom{n}{2k}x^k-A=0.
$$
Since this is a polynomial equation of order $m=\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor$, it has (taking into account the multiplicity) exactly $m$ roots $x_i(A)$, parametrically dependent on $A$, which can be easily found numerically. The corresponding $B$ can be then calculated as 
$$
B_i(A)=\sum_{0\leq k}\binom{n}{2k+1}x_i^k(A).
$$

The numerical calculations do not support a speculation that there can be a general *simple* formula to express all $B_i$ (or even one of them) in terms of $A$. This however does not exclude a simple expression for some specific values of $A$. For example if $A=1$ one of the roots is $0$ and the corresponding $B$ is $n$.

Comment: Thanks @user for your answer.

Comment: @boaz You are welcome, but probably you expected a different answer. What was the motivation behind the question?